# zfs deduplication "low" ratio

Tags: filesystems, solaris, backup, zfs

In Solaris 11, in a pool named `mypool` I activated deduplication with

```
zfs set dedup=on mypool
```

Then I created two 100 MB file: `file1` and its copy `file1copy`. Only their names are different: their contents is the same.

The mountpoint of `mypool` is `/mypool`. If I copy both `file1` and `file1copy` into `/mypool`, the output of

```
zpool list mypool
```

indicates a `DEDUP` ratio of barely `1.34x`. Why??

Then, following [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/panni/entry/zfs_deduplication) guide I created a filesystem with

```
zfs create -o dedup=on -o mypool/archive
```

and then two users' filesystems `mypool/archive/a` and `mypool/archive/b` which inherited the deduplication from the parent filesystem.

If now I copy `file1` into `mypool/archive/a` and `file1copy` into `mypool/archive/b` there is still a `DEDUP` ratio of `1.34x`. It becomes `2` only if I put the *same* file, say `file1`, into *both* `mypool/archive/a` and `mypool/archive/b`. Why??

Can a simple name difference strongly tear down deduplication? Shouldn't deduplication act at block level?

---

1) Output of `zdb -S mypool`

```
Simulated DDT histogram:

bucket              allocated                       referenced          
______   ______________________________   ______________________________
refcnt   blocks   LSIZE   PSIZE   DSIZE   blocks   LSIZE   PSIZE   DSIZE
------   ------   -----   -----   -----   ------   -----   -----   -----
     1    1.48K    189M    189M    189M    1.48K    189M    189M    189M
     2      800    100M    100M   99.9M    1.56K    200M    200M    200M
 Total    2.26K    289M    289M    288M    3.04K    389M    389M    388M

dedup = 1.35, compress = 1.00, copies = 1.00, dedup * compress / copies = 1.35
```

2) Output of `zdb -b mypool`

```
Traversing all blocks to verify nothing leaked ...

    No leaks (block sum matches space maps exactly)

    bp count:            3679
    bp logical:     410970112      avg: 111707
    bp physical:    408433664      avg: 111017     compression:   1.01
    bp allocated:   615948288      avg: 167422     compression:   0.67
    bp deduped:     157286400    ref>1:    800   deduplication:   1.26
    SPA allocated:  458661888     used: 76.47%
```

In both `mypool/archive/a` and `mypool/archive/b` folders there was also another file.

Comment: What is the output from `zdb -S mypool` and `zdb -b mypool`?

Comment: I edited my question with that outputs.

Comment: The name for the file should not have any impact on deduplication. I strongly suggest you look at the contents of `file1` and `file1copy` and whether they really have the same content (e.g. with `sha1sum`).

Answer (score 1):

Not all data is "dedupable". There is an article here that explains [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/o11-113-size-zfs-dedup-1354231.html)

Comment: Thank you for the article. But the blocks of the two files should generate the same hash (they are the same!) and so should be dedupable. Maybe the other files in the filesystem can influence the deduplication?